# Exchange enrypted messages with a single recipient

Tags: encryption, portable

I need to exchange **encrypted** messages with another party. These would be in the form of email like communication (not instant chat). The solution needs to be portable (USB stick).

I've tried "Portable Thunderbird/Enigmail/Gnupg/Hotmail account" but it's just impossible to setup portable, countless meaningless error messages. Anyway, I would prefer something more straightforward.

**Notes:**

- We won't know each others IP addresses.
- Our computers will often be switched off.
- Encryption would ideally be using a common password.

**Is there a solution to this?**

Answer (score 1):

How about this very primitive way?

1. Create a small/tiny TrueCrypt volume using [TrueCrypt Portable](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=truecrypt-portable) with a **good** password known to you and your recipient.
2. Mount the volume, write you message in a file in the volume.
3. Upload the volume somewhere<sup>*</sup> or email the volume to your recipient.

   <sup>**`*`**</sup> You can share it using Google Docs, Dropbox or even Rapidshare if your password is good enough.